# Getting data from database based on user id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Hi I am trying to get data from the database where the user can click on a person name and be redirected to some other page to see the person detail example like "user id = 1". Any idea on how to do it? If possible could you show me some example on how to do it thanks

Below is a screenshot on what I have done so far, the name below are in href so that it can redirect the user to another page and see the person details
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) for this one.

```
User::find($userid);
```

or using [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)

```
$users = DB::table('users')where('id','=', $userid)->get();
```

Comment: won't a $userid variable not found error happen because it isn't defined

Comment: you should pass it together with your url something like `localhost:80/laravel/user/1`

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function for redirect in javascript with parameter is User ID. After that use your routes to get parameter (user id) on your link and write a query mysql in your controller to get data of this user id. Finally , you bring all of data from this user to your view.

```
function Redirect(userid) {
    window.location = 'http://yourdomain.com/profile/'+userid;
}
```

in your view add event onclick to username.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return Redirect('{{$userid}}')">bob</a>
```

in routes/web.php add new route:

```
Route::get('/{userid}','Controller@index');
```

in your controller:

```
$UserID=$request->input('userid');
```

now your parameter on your link will stored in $UserID. You can use this value to query data and show it on you view.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sample code of how to get the desired user from the data base.

```
$dbUser="root";
$dbPassword="root";
$dbServer="localhost:8889";
$dbName="test_database";

$connection = new mysqli($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);


if($connection->connect_errno)
{
    exit("Database Connection Failed. Reason: ".$connection->connect_error);
}else{
    echo "Connection successful..;
}

$query = "SELECT id,first_name,last_name FROM Author where user_id= XXXX ";
$resultObj = $connection->query($query);

if ($resultObj->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while ($singleRowFromQuery = $resultObj->fetch_array()) 
    {
        print_r($singleRowFromQuery);
        echo "Author: ".$singleRowFromQuery['first_name'].PHP_EOL."<br>";
    }
}


$resultObj->close();
$connection->close();
```

Make sure you replace the user_id appropriately and provide appropriate declaration.

you also pass data through the call url in the anchor tag using `.. url ..?user_id=XXX`

Comment: But how do you do it in laravel? Like what should I put inside my controller to get user_id

Comment: Try this one.. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/form-select-box-formselect?page=1